# TOR aborts, locks up computer

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows

Various web pages cause Tor Browser 5.5.4 on Windows 7 to abort which, in turn, locks up the computer.
Can only reboot with NMI.

Are there readable abort logs?

This started happening in 5.5.3

Comment: Please give more details about this behaviour. It seems you use the Tor Browser, right? Can you tell on which sites this is happening? Did you change the security slider in Tor Browser?